# Java random number with given length

Tags: java, random

I need to genarate a random number with exactly 6 digits in Java. I know i could loop 6 times over a randomizer but is there a nother way to do this in the standard Java SE?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/java-generating-random-number-in-a-range

Comment: Voting to reopen. Random number in *range* is slightly different from random number with given *length*.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Generate a number in the range from `100000` to `999999`.

```
// pseudo code
int n = 100000 + random_float() * 900000;
```

For more details see the documentation for [Random](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

Comment: random_float() is a pseudo-code function (i.e. it does not exist) that returns a random floating-point number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive).

Comment: Thank you this worked great! Got any solution for my follow up q also?

Comment: Bad pseudo code and bad attitude

Answer (score 93):

**To generate a 6-digit number:**

Use [`Random`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) and [`nextInt`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) as follows:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int n = 100000 + rnd.nextInt(900000);
```

Note that `n` will never be 7 digits (1000000) since `nextInt(900000)` can at most return `899999`.

> ***So how do I randomize the last 5 chars that can be either A-Z or 0-9?***

Here's a simple solution:

```
// Generate random id, for example 283952-V8M32
char[] chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".toCharArray();
Random rnd = new Random();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder((100000 + rnd.nextInt(900000)) + "-");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    sb.append(chars[rnd.nextInt(chars.length)]);

return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 10):

If you need to specify the exact charactor length, we have to avoid values with 0 in-front.

Final String representation must have that exact character length.

```
String GenerateRandomNumber(int charLength) {
        return String.valueOf(charLength < 1 ? 0 : new Random()
                .nextInt((9 * (int) Math.pow(10, charLength - 1)) - 1)
                + (int) Math.pow(10, charLength - 1));
    }
```

Comment: Have to be careful with Integer overflow. Overall this is a clean solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
public int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
    return (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int rand = (new Random()).getNextInt(900000) + 100000;
```

**EDIT:** Fixed off-by-1 error and removed invalid solution.

Comment: Mod a huge number by 899999 won't necessarily result in a uniform randomization.

Comment: Should be `nextInt()` instead of `getNextInt()`

Answer (score 0):

For the follow-up question, you can get a number between  36^5 and 36^6 and convert it in base 36

UPDATED:

using this code

http://javaconfessions.com/2008/09/convert-between-base-10-and-base-62-in_28.html

It's written
`BaseConverterUtil.toBase36(60466176+r.nextInt(2116316160))`

but in your use case, it can be optimized by using a `StringBuilder` and having the number in the reverse order ie 71 should be converted in Z1 instead of 1Z

EDITED:

Comment: Thanks for yore answer but I'm not sure how you mean? Coudl you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Generate exactly 6 digit numbers in the range from 100_000 to 999_999.

```
new Random.nextInt(100_000, 1_000_000)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the below code to generate 6-digit number in Java.

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100000, 999999);

Answer (score -1):

Would that work for you?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.out.println(r.nextInt(100000) * 0.000001);
}
```

}

result e.g. 0.019007

Comment: seems I was a little bit late :)

Comment: You can skip the argument to `currentTimeMillis`. The `Random()` constructor has a better approach.

Answer (score -3):

Generate a random number (which is always between 0-1) and multiply by 1000000

```
Math.round(Math.random()*1000000);
```