# How can I generate a random 15 digit-long in java

Tags: java, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java random number with given length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392693/java-random-number-with-given-length)

I have been trying to generate a 15 digit long number in java but it seems I have failed to do it so far as using:

This is producing a maximum of 10 digits.

```
  Random random = new Random();
  int rand15Digt = random.nextInt(15);
```

How can I generate it successfully?

Comment: oh i forgot to add that i used a number that is a power of ten as the seed to the random generator. just to make sure that i have the required number of digits.

Comment: the seed of random won't affect the number of digits of your output

Comment: Your current code produces an `int` between 0 and 15. Are you looking to produce a number that has fifteen characters when represented in decimal? I.e. something between `100,000,000,000,000` and `999,999,999,999,999`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392693/java-random-number-with-given-length

Comment: yes, exactly something like that.

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:swing], [tag:javascript] *or* [tag:java-ee].  Please choose tags more carefully

Comment: yeah, about the tags: sorry about that but the question wasn't accepted till i added them - 
it kept on saying 
"Ooops, question doesn't meet our requirements" or something like that.
still sorry for that.

Comment: like i said above. i added about the power thing, it works for seeds 10 and below. above that, it goes berserk and gives wierd results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)'s method    `public long nextLong()`

Comment: ok, thanks. let me give it a shot

Comment: well, it seems long doesn't take any parameters, so how can i ensure that the generated figure is 15 digits long?

Answer (score 4):

To begin with, an `int` can hold numbers between `-2,147,483,648` and `2,147,483,647`.

Use [`Random.nextLong()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextLong%28%29)

Comment: @DuncanJones, 000000000000012 is a `15 digit result`. The OP has not asked for ("a number between 10+e15 and 10+e16-1").

Comment: Fair point! I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: Still i dont get how can ensure that my result is a 15 digits long.
.nextLong() is yeilding values greater longer than 15 digits so far.

Comment: @user1825142 You need to be specific about what you want. As SJuan76 states, any number can be considered *x*-digits long if you format it as such. If you are looking for a specific number range, make it clear in the question.

Comment: @DuncanJones - well consider it to be from 
 
 100000000000000 to 999999999999999

Comment: @SJuan76 Apologies for the quick-draw -1. I've made a tiny edit to your answer to allow me to give a +1.

Answer (score 4):

Any number can be formatted into 15 decimal digits when presented as a string. This is achieved when the number is converted to a String, e.g.:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%015d", 1));

// prints: 000000000000001
```

If you want to generate a random number that lies between `100,000,000,000,000` and `999,999,999,999,999` then you can [perform a trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5392715/474189) such as:

```
Random random = new Random();    
long n = (long) (100000000000000L + random.nextFloat() * 900000000000000L);
```

If your ultimate goal is to have a 15-character string containing random decimal digits, and you're happy with third-party libraries, consider Apache commons [`RandomStringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html):

```
boolean useLetters = false;
boolean useNumbers = true;
int stringLength = 15;

String result = RandomStringUtils.random(stringLength, useLetters, useNumbers)
```

Comment: -1: The OP has asked for a number, not a String.

Comment: ok, let me download this and try it. i'll get back to you ASAP.

Comment: @SJuan76 Touché :-) I made the assumption he was going to be using a string eventually, but I could well be wrong.

Comment: @Duncan Jones; how do i add this RandomStringUtils library to my code?
or where can i get it from. apparently its already there somewhere but i cant download it or import it, or directly use it.

Comment: @Duncan Jones - you are right as well. i will use it as a string eventually. so how can i get that to work. i mean add to my code.

Comment: @user1825142 You need to [download commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi). Or just use the trick I added to the question above.

Comment: @SJuan76 The question is long since dead, but I've edited my answer to reflect the different options available.

Comment: @Duncan Jones - thanks alot. that quite did the trick :)!!

Comment: Fair is fair. I was a quick downvoter in my young years, too :-)

Answer (score 1):

What about trying `BigInteger`, see this StackOverflow link for more information [Random BigInteger Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290057/how-to-generate-a-random-biginteger-value-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

In Hibernate have `UUIDGenerator` class using this we can create Secure Random and Unique Number also.

```
public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
        throws HibernateException {
    String uuid = (String)super.generate(session, object);
    return uuid.substring(uuid.length()-15, uuid.length());
}
```

i think this is best way to Generate Unique and also Random Number...

Comment: Thanks but i have tried and i can't get this to work. its creating alot of both run time and compilation errors.