# Field with random int value

Tags: java, random, object-to-string

I'm writing a program that simulates simple bank account activities and I was wondering how to do it so that if I create a new Account without any parameters, it receives random 7digit identification number that is shown as String. The way I do, I only receive java.util.Random@2a0364ef in output. 
Looking forward to any help and additional comments on this question as it is the first one I've posted on this website.

```
    import java.util.Random;

    class Account {

    String id;
    double stan;
    int num;
    static int counter;

    public Account() {
        **id = randomId().toString();**
        stan = 0;
        num = ++counter;

    }

    public Account(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        stan = 0;
        num = ++counter;

    }

    public Account(String id, double mon) {
        stan = 0;
        this.id = id;
        this.stan = mon;
        num = ++counter;

    }

    **static String randomId() {
        Random rand = new Random(7);
        return String.valueOf(rand);**
    }

    String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    double getStan() {
        return stan;
    }

    int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account's id " + getId() + " and balance " + getStan();
    }
}

public class Exc7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account account = new Account("0000001"),
                acount0 = new Account("0000002", 1000),
                acount1 = new Account();




        System.out.println(account + "\n" + account0 + "\n" + account1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
Random rand = new Random(7);
return String.valueOf(Math.abs(rand.nextInt()));
```

Right now you are representing the `Random` instance.

Instead printing the `String` representation of the mathematical absolute of the next `int` of your  random will do the trick.

The `Math.abs` part is important, otherwise you might have negative numbers.

Comment: Firstly, thanks. Secondly, I also made mistake to assume that if I put 7 into Random it will give me a number with seven digits. Should I just put 9999999 to receive a number within this range or do it other way?

Comment: @Konrad you're welcome! To be honest I was distracted and tricked as well by the `Random` constructor: indeed it doesn't define number of digits but rather the random seed. You can start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392693/java-random-number-with-given-length) for the specific number of digits - otherwise just truncate your `String`.

Answer (score 2):

Change  `return String.valueOf(rand);`

To

```
 return String.valueOf(rand.nextInt());
```

**Reason**:

You are passing random Object to `valueOf` method, not the value you need. Call `nextInt()` method on it to get the desired random value.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
return String.valueOf(rand.nextInt());
```

otherwise you will get the string representation of the `Random` object and not of a random `int` that it can produce.