# Generate 6 digit pin in java

Tags: java

I have a requirement where users will have to see a pin generated for an order and has to be shared/used as authorization code for that particular order.

So I am looking for a library which can generate random unique pins of 6 digit length which can be used for each transaction.

Please share your thoughts on this..

Thanks..

Comment: have you done any research about "How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?"

Comment: With only 6 digits, the generated pins can only be unique for a short period of time.

Comment: you can find your answer here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)
and your range would be between 100000 and 999999

Comment: `int n = 100000 + random_float() * 900000;` and already a similar answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392693/java-random-number-with-given-length)

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Answer (score 3):

You can try **SecureRandom**

Extract From [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/random-vs-secure-random-numbers-java/)

**java.security.SecureRandom class**: This class provides a cryptographically strong random number generator (RNG). A cryptographically strong random number minimally complies with the statistical random number generator tests specified in FIPS 140-2, Security Requirements for Cryptographic Modules, section 4.9.1. Additionally, SecureRandom must produce non-deterministic output. Therefore any seed material passed to a SecureRandom object must be unpredictable, and all SecureRandom output sequences must be cryptographically strong.

**java.util.Random class**: The classes defined in Random are not cryptographically strong, and the numbers chosen are not completely random because a definite mathematical algorithm (based on Donald E. Knuth’s subtractive random number generator algorithm) is used to select them. Therefore, it is not safe to use this class for tasks that require high level of security, like creating a random password etc.

Example using SecureRandom:

```
 SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
 int myInt = sr.nextInt(9000000) + 1000000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the Apache library.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
</dependency>

int random = RandomUtils.nextInt(1, 7);
```

Ref: https://www.java67.com/2018/01/3-ways-to-generate-random-integers-on.html

Comment: `RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(6)` generates 6 digit random code.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a library which can generate random **unique** pins

If you generate a random integer, it's not guaranteed to always be unique. With 6 numeric digits, there's a one in a million chance that users could get the same order number. You could increase the number of digits or also allow alphabet characters to decrease the chances of getting the same order number.

However, the only way to truly ensure each order number is unique is to keep a running tally of total number of orders. Then each user's order number is literally the n'th order you've received.

Comment: For the application that the OP is asking for, the PIN only needs to be unique for a short period of time, 1-2 minutes.

Answer (score -3):

You can manually generate pin in java using built-in **java.util.Random class **. You can use this in authentication to generate six digits random number pin.

```
 int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(1000000); 
 if rand_int1 has 6 digits
             print(rand_int1)
 else
          generate(again)
```

this will generate a six digit random number.

Comment: it may generate numbers which have less than 6 digits.

Comment: it can generate digits < 100 000

Comment: @fahime you mean like `000111`?

Comment: @talex no I mean a number like 78168, it's the real output of this code.

Comment: @fahime depends on how you print it. You can print it as `078168`. Or you mean leading zeroes not allowed?

Comment: Never ever use `Random` for anything which has to do with security!

Comment: @talex maybe you are right, but I got the question in this way that adding zeros is not allowed!

Comment: Isn't it  easier just use `random(1000000 - 100000)+100000` to ensure that first digit is at least 1?